# Why don't I see any Vulnerabilities in SonarQube Security Reports?

Tags: javascript, security, sonarqube

Ive scanned my project with SonarQube 7.4 and I dont get any security issue.

[image]

Ive tried including an obvious SQL Injection vulnerability but its still not detected.

```
const query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE custID='" + request.params.id + "'";
```

So Im missing some extra configuration or plugin?